# What will happen if i have chrome custom tab in my app but user has chrome version less than 45?

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

What will happen in a case where my app implements custom chrome tabs but user has chrome version < 45??? And how to ensure that compatibility is maintained for everyone?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the documentation here:  https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs it will launch the system browser or the user's default browser if a suitable version of Chrome is not available.

Comment: You can also check for the availability of a browser supporting Custom Tabs and decide what to do (open in a WebView or use the default browser) if a browser that supports its is not installed. Check the following code to see how to check for it: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs#preparing-for other browsers